# Change GWT CellTable style only for concrete table

Tags: gwt, coding-style, gwt-2.2-celltable

How to change gwt cell table style. I am not using ui binder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6144 (which is *not* a bug, but there's the full explanation there, and even some sample code). Add a comment if you need more details and I'll update my anwer.